# GPU's memory is far from zero, why?

Tags: memory, memory-management, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I have a GPU with the total memory of 6 Gb. However, around 500 Mb (or 400 Mb) is always in use (see the screenshot below) prohibiting me to exploit that portion of memory for my own needs. How to release that memory, so I would have available all 6 Gb for myself?

[image]

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac? Which GPU?

Comment: Is it running your display?

Comment: Windows 10. How can I check if it is running my display? The model of GPU is on the screenshot

Comment: Is your display plugged into your GPU?

Comment: @LeviBarnes yes, probably that is the reason